# How to dismiss a view controller after getting response from two separate web services

Tags: ios, iphone

In my current project I came across a situation where I need to call two separate web services and dismiss present view controller once I get response from both the services. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Till now what did you try?show the coding

Answer (score 0):

@Karthik Reddy:  You could use an "If" conditional statement to confirm when you get a response and 'if' you do then use the following code to dismiss view controller...

```
dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```